# Change replication factor of selected objects

Tags: cassandra, database-replication, hazelcast, infinispan, openstack-swift

Is there any cloud storage system (i.e Cassandra, Hazelcast, Openstack Swift) where we can **change the replication factor of selected objects**? For instance lets say, we have found out hotspot objects in the system so we can increase the replication factor as a solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In Cassandra the replication factor is controlled based on keyspaces.  So you first define a keyspace by specifying the replication factor the keyspace should have in each of your data centers.  Then within a keyspace, you create database tables, and those tables are replicated according to the keyspace they are defined in.  Objects are then stored in rows in a table using a primary key.

You can change the replication factor for a keyspace at any time by using the "alter keyspace" CQL command.  To update the cluster to use the new replication factor, you would then run "nodetool repair" for each node (most installations run this periodically anyway for anti-entropy).

Then if you use for example the Cassandra java driver, you can specify the load balancing policy to use when accessing the cluster, such as round robin, and token aware policy.  So if you have multiple replicas of the the table holding the objects, then the load of accessing the object could be set to round robin on just the nodes that have a copy of the row you are accessing.  If you are using a read consistency level of ONE, then this would spread out the read load.

So the granularity of this is not at the object level, but at the table level.  If you had all your objects stored in one table, then changing the replication factor would change it for all objects in that table and not just one.  You could have multiple keyspaces with different replication factors and keep high demand objects in a keyspace with a high RF, and less frequently accessed objects in a keyspace with a low RF.

Another way you could reduce the hot spot for an object in Cassandra is to make additional copies of it by inserting it into additional rows of a table.  The rows are accessed on nodes by the compound partition key, so one field of the partition key could be a "copy_number" value, and when you go to read the object, you randomly set a copy_number value (from 0 to the number of copy rows you have) so that the load of reading the object will likely hit a different node for each read (since rows are hashed across the cluster based on the partition key).  This approach would give you more granularity at the object level compared to changing the replication factor for the whole table, at the cost of more programming work to manage randomly reading different rows.

Answer (score 1):

In Infinispan, you can also set number of owners (replicas) on each cache (equivalent to Hazelcast's map or Cassandra's table), but not for one specific entry. Since the routing information (aka consistent hash table) does not contain all keys but splits the hashCode() 32-bit range to variable amount of segments, and then specifies the distribution only for these segments, there's no way to specify the number of replicas per entry.

Theoretically, with specially forged keys and custom consistent hash table factory, you could achieve something similar even in one cache (certain sorts of keys would be replicated different amount of times), but that would require coding with deep understanding of the system.

Anyway, the reader would have to know the number of replicas in advance as this would be part of the routing information (cache in simple case, special keys as described above), therefore, it's not really practical unless the reader can know that.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to use the replication factor for the sake of speeding up reads.

The regular Map (IMap) implementation, uses a master slave(s) setup, so all reads will go through the master. But there is a special setting available, so you are also allowed to read from backups. So if you have a 10 node cluster, and have a backup count of 5, there will be in total 6 members that have the information stored. 5 members in the cluster will hit the master, and 5 members in the cluster will hit the backup (since they have the backup locally available).

There also is a fully replicated map available, here every item is send to every machine. So in a 10 node cluster, all reads will be local since every machine has the same data.

In case of the IMap, we don't provide control on the number of backups on the key/value level. So the whole map is configured with a certain backup-count.